# Searching criteria in Mongo db documents with Yii

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

How can I create a search form/criteria for "one-to many" relations: let's say "select all teams with crowd > 10.000".

I'm using MongoRecord extension (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mongorecord/) as a basic active record for MongoDb.

I created a GridView with Yii based on a collection from a mongo db (it works for me). 
One of my document`s collection has a structure like this:

```
{
_id":1,
"teamId":2453,
"teamName":"Team A",
"competition":["Competition A","Competition B"],
"matches":
    [
        {
            "_id":147852,
            "crowd":10234,
            "yellowCards":2,
            "scorers" [{....}]
            ....
        }
    ]
...
}
```

My documents:

```
$teams = MongoTeam::model()->findAll();    

My dataProvider is:
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($teams, array(
        'id'=>'_id',
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                 '_id', 'teamId', 'teamName', 'matches', ...
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20,
        ),
    ));
    $this->render('index', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

And in the view I have something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Team ID',          
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->teamID)'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Team Name',          
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->teamName)'
        ),
        ...
```

But I'm not able to create filters with criteria for subdocuments (my case: "matches"). I don't want to use any other mongoDB extension/module etc.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: MongoReord has not been maintained for years as such I am unsure if anyone here can help you with its programming, you would be better off using a more complete extension.

Comment: I saw but it`s all I need (of course, I made some changes on it)

Comment: To filter you would need a function or a class that can accept the incoming GET, filter it and apply the filter, you haven't got nearly enough code, not even for root document filtering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=array(
   'matches.crowd'=>array('$gt'=>10000),
   'matches.$'=>1
);
$teams = MongoTeam::model()->findAll($query);
```

You can use like this. But you must not use a data provider like that. Because it will generate too much rows into the $teams var. You must use criteria for data providers. I am doing that with [YiiMongoDbSuite](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/) it has EMongoCriteria and EMongoDataProvider classes to accomplish that.